# How to remove the styling from a newly generated P tag in Froala editor?

Tags: froala

When generating a new `P` tag, the styles from the previous `P` are taken into consideration in froala editor. How can we prevent this behavior? Right now I'll have to request the user to change the `P` tag to a `DIV` so that the default block generated will not get the style. But it is a bit painful.

Code inside the preview of the froala:

```
<p style="color: red;">hello there</p>
```

The next `P` tag generated will have the same style applied even if I don't want it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying multiple ways, we can prevent the styling to take over the next element by adding empty `P` tag at the end of the content each time we add some styling.

```
this.editorInstance.html.insert(`<p style="color:red">A block element</p><p></p>`);
```

By adding an empty `P` tag, we create a new block without any styles.